# cannot access wordpress frontend page without proxy_set_header Host

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

I use nginx as reverse proxy for apache wordpress site. But I cannot access word.com frontend page if I comment out the proxy_set_header part, it just redirect to 127.0.0.1 in my brower. Who can explain it for me?
Nginx settings:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name word.com
    charset utf-8;
    index index.htm index.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/word-access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/word-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: this maybe because the wordpress database has static url. Try find and replace plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Comment: @sking, i reinstall the wordpress and the question is still there, so i think exist other reasons. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a `proxy_set_header` directive, `nginx` will set the proxied `Host` header to `127.0.0.0:8080`.

Apache will see this hostname and use it when constructing certain response to the browser (such as a redirect).

It is usual to specify `proxy_set_header Host $host;`. The default value is only useful in limited cases, such as contacting remote resources.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for more.

Comment: you're awesome! I see the nginx proxy_set_header ducument you shared with me. Can you show me some document for why Apache response to the browser redirect to 127.0.0.1?